Bijection between binary strings of length $n$ without consecutive $1$s and binary strings of length $n+1$ without an odd number of consecutive $1$s
It can be proved by recurrence relation that both the number of binary strings of length $n$ without consecutive $1$s and the number of binary strings of length $n+1$ without an odd number of consecutive $1$s are both equal to the $(n+2)$-th Fibonacci number $F_{n+2}$. Therefore the two numbers are equal.
Is there a bijective proof for that?

Let $S_n$ be binary string of length $n$ without consecutive ones.
Let $T_n$ be binary strings of length $n$  without odd number of consecutive ones.
Given $x\in S_n$, consider $0x$. This still has no consecutive ones. For each $1$ in $0x$, change the $0$ behind it to $1$. Example: $100101 \to 0100101 \to 1101111 $

Verify the new string is indeed in $T_{n+1}$

Verify that this reduction is injective and surjective.


